# Magento: remove footer from wrapper

Tags: magento, layout, themes, footer

I need to figure out how to remove a footer from the wrapper and add it on the end of page. I would like to use a footer that has 100% of width of the browser resolution, which is impossible while it’s wrapped.

I guess I need to change page.xml in my theme. Or local.xml? I want to do it in correct way...

In page.xml I found:

```
    <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
            <label>Page Footer</label>
            <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
        </block>
        <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
        <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
    </block>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make footer container absolute, so it jumps out of normal flow and then set width to 100% of screen size. I preffer your magento instalation has class 'footer-container' couse mine has.
html structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="footer-container">
            <div class="footer">
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

style.css

```
.footer-container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

after that you need to set inner div width and center it:

```
.footer{
    width: 900px;  /* set width you want */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Ok, this way I get the footer-container out of the normal flow. But how do I set width of the footer-container for the whole width of browser? This width: 100%; still refers to the width of .page. I need to set a background-image repeating for whole browser width on the bottom of the page.

Comment: Do yo have it online? Can i take a look?

Comment: No, unfortunately not yet. I guess the problem is that even though I have taken the footer-container out of the regular flow, it is still a child of layout-grid instead of being on the same level.

Comment: Ok, you can do it by changing *.phtml files. Copy them from app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/ to app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/page/ and then modify them by moving <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?> few lines lower so that line is outside of .wrapper .  Now it should be out of   wrappers div.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try that. Is there a way to do it via adjusting the xml files? To properly follow module structure..